# Error when trying to run TrueCrypt 7.1a x64

Tags: truecrypt

When I run TrueCrypt 7.1a x64 I get this error :

```
1: /usr/bin/truecrypt: Syntax error: ")" unexpected
```

How to work around this error?

Comment: Have you made the file executable? Right-click, Properties, Permissions, tick "Allow executing file as program".

Comment: What is the text you type to run truecrypt

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. I realized I had installed the x64 version instead of x86.

I ran `truecrypt-uninstall.sh` and then installed the x86 version and TrueCrypt is running OK now. Hope it helps.